# scheduling tasks in linux kernel module everyday at a user provided time

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am writing a linux kernel module which schedules a task using schedule_delayed_work at a particular time which in turn send a signal to a user space program to do some task.
What I did is manually given the time in milliseconds (say 5000ms) and changed it to jiffies using "msec to jiffies" function and tested it and worked.

My use case is that the user will give a time (say 5 pm) and the module has to schedule it to send the signal everyday at 5 pm to the user program. I am totally confused in how to calculate the milliseconds from the user given time for everyday basis.

I used workqueue to create a queue and then the task to accomplish and doing the scheduling.

My kernel module:

```
    static void wq_handler_function(struct work_struct *work);
    static unsigned long delay;

    static struct workqueue_struct *my_wq; // my workqueue
    static DECLARE_DELAYED_WORK(my_work, wq_handler_function); //my work/task


    static void wq_handler_function(struct work_struct *work)
    {
       printk(KERN_DEBUG "handler function called\n");
       if(my_wq)
       {
          /*Do some work like sending signal to user space*/
          schedule_delayed_work(&my_work, delay); /*reschedule after the first scheduled time finished*/
       }
    }

    int sig_init_module(void)
    {
       printk(KERN_DEBUG "signal module initiated\n");
       delay = msecs_to_jiffies(5000); //Manually given 5000ms (5 sec) for scheuling
       if(!my_wq)
          my_wq = create_workqueue("my_queue");

          if(my_wq)
          {
             schedule_delayed_work(&my_work, delay); /*schedule for the first time while module initiates*/
          }
        return 0;
     }

     void sig_cleanup_module(void)
     {
        flush_scheduled_work();
        cancel_delayed_work_sync(&my_work);

        flush_workqueue(my_wq);
        destroy_workqueue(my_wq);

        printk(KERN_DEBUG "signal module removed\n");
     }

     module_init(sig_init_module);
     module_exit(sig_cleanup_module);
```

Kindly help me to have a solution for this. Thanks in advance!!!.

Comment: This sort of task is usually accomplished in user space, not in the kernel. Why are you trying to write a kernel module to handle this?

Comment: Could you please give an idea how this can be implemented in user space @duskwuff

Comment: Can you explain why you're trying to write this as a kernel module? Do you believe it's impossible to do it without one?

Comment: I am not sure but I think kernel module will be the correct way. You can find the actual process I am trying in the below comments for the answer provided by "employee of the month" .

Comment: Please advice if there is any other way to achieve this..

Comment: @MohamedHussain What's wrong with [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)?

Comment: I am accessing the embedded system from GUI in  a system and an android application using the ip addr of the embedded device. Am creating a profile to switch ON/OFF a  light/fan at regular time (say everyday 5 pm) and need to schedule this. So from app point of view it's difficult to use cron. So am going for kernel module. @tangrs

Comment: Or even just `sleep()`. Either way -- what you're trying to do here is a completely normal task, which has literally been implemented _thousands of times_ before in userspace applications. You do not need a kernel module.

Comment: @MohamedHussain Trust me, if you think using cron/sleep/any other user-space method is difficult, good luck writing a kernel module. Whatever solution you come up with in user-space will be 10x easier than writing a kernel module.

Comment: @tangrs   Ok.. Then I will try to implement in user space. Could you give me an idea how to do the same in user space.

Comment: @MohamedHussain: What makes you think using cron would be difficult? cron is definitely the right choice for this and you should use it. Keep note that also unprivileged users can install cron jobs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why kernel modification would be desirable or necessary. If you want something periodically done (e.g. log rotation), add it to cron. Another option would be to use timerfd.

Comment: This is actually to get the user time from an android application from a customer and save it to schedule the task from the embedded system running linux under the hood which inturn invokes some code in the userspace.

Comment: I still don't see how kernel modifications are of any use. What if there is a reboot? Where do you store the data? You can just create a userspace daemon and have the app talk to that over e.g. a unix socket.

Comment: Am using a RESTful server which listens on some port and another tcp code with another port. From that RESTful server, user given time is received using the IP and port number and transferred to the TCP code.

Comment: From the TCP code, kernel module is initiated and scheduling is done. When the scheduled time came, kernel module will send a signal to TCP code to invoke some other process. Am storing the data in sqlite db

Comment: So the thing which would tell the kernel to notify it later, why it can't use timerfd which effectively would accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

use mktime() function in kernel code which takes the wall time as arguments and directly returns the jiffies value.
For info about mktime, see this http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-2

Comment: I think mktime() returns the epoch time not the jiffies value @user_3093890